How to check if MDM is active on an Android device?
I am working on an Android project that involves Mobile Device Management (MDM). I need to programmatically check whether MDM is active on the device.
I have explored device administrator and device policy manager classes, but I am unsure how to accurately detect if the device is being managed by an MDM solution.
Here are a few key points:
I'm working with Kotlin.
The project targets Android 14.
I need a reliable method to check if an MDM solution (like Miradore or Intune) is managing the device.
Could someone guide me on how to achieve this or point me toward any relevant APIs or classes in Android?
Any help would be appreciated.

This question is similar to: Detect devices running MDM (mobile device management). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use:
adb shell dumpsys device_policy

You should either find an admin or deviceowner.
Another option that might work for you is: adb shell getprop ro.device_owner
